# Avoid Null Value in JSP Table Textbox if no entry in database

Tags: mysql, jsp

```
String sql="SELECT a.ID,a.VISITOR_TEXT,a.COMPANY_TEXT,a.CONTACT,a.PERSON_TO_MEET,a.DEPARTMENT_TEXT,a.FLOOR,b.BELONGING_TYPE,b.BELONGING_TEXT ,a.INTIME, c.EXIT_TIME FROM tm_visitor a  LEFT JOIN tm_belonging b ON b.BID=a.ID LEFT JOIN tm_exit c ON c.ID=a.ID limit "+i+",10";

System.out.println(sql);
ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(sql);
while(rs.next())
    {
    ar.add(rs.getInt("ID"));
    ar.add(rs.getObject("VISITOR_TEXT"));
    ar.add(rs.getObject("COMPANY_TEXT"));
    ar.add(rs.getObject("CONTACT"));
    ar.add(rs.getObject("PERSON_TO_MEET"));
    ar.add(rs.getObject("DEPARTMENT_TEXT"));
    ar.add(rs.getObject("FLOOR"));
    ar.add(rs.getObject("BELONGING_TYPE"));
    ar.add(rs.getObject("BELONGING_TEXT"));
    ar.add(rs.getObject("INTIME"));
    ar.add(rs.getObject("EXIT_TIME"));

    }

<tr>
    <td align="center"><input type="text" name="id" value="<%=itr.next()%>" readonly size="15"></td>
    <td align="center"><input type="text" name="visitorname" value="<%=itr.next()%>" readonly size="20"></td>
    <td align="center"><input type="text" name="company" value="<%=itr.next()%>" readonly size="20"></td>
    <td align="center"><input type="text" name="contact" value="<%=itr.next()%>" readonly size="10"></td>
    <td align="center"><input type="text" name="whometomeet" value="<%=itr.next()%>" readonly size="20"></td>
    <td align="center"><input type="text" name="department" value="<%=itr.next()%>" readonly size="20"></td>
    <td align="center"><input type="text" name="floor" value="<%=itr.next()%>" readonly size="7"></td>
    <td align="center"><input type="text" name="btype" value="<%=itr.next()%>" readonly size="15"></td>
    <td align="center"><input type="text" name="bel" value="<%=itr.next()%>" readonly size="15"></td>
    <td align="center"><input type="text" name="intime" value="<%=itr.next()%>" readonly size="20"></td>
    <td align="center"><input type="text" name="exittime" value="<%=itr.next()%>" readonly size="20"></td>



</tr>
```

After executing above query if value in value in tm_exit.EXIT_TIME is not present then display NULL in JSP table text box how do I avoid this

I tried:

```
<%!
String blanknull(String s) {
  return (s == null) ? "" : s;
}
%>
```

but no use, please help?

here is query which I am using to fetch data

```
SELECT a.ID,a.VISITOR_TEXT,a.COMPANY_TEXT,a.CONTACT,a.PERSON_TO_MEET,a.DEPARTMENT_TEXT,‌​a.FLOOR,b.BELONG ING_TYPE,b.BELONGING_TEXT ,a.INTIME, c.(ifnull(EXIT_TIME,'NA')) as EXIT_TIME FROM tm_visitor a LEFT JOIN tm_b elonging b ON b.BID=a.ID LEFT JOIN tm_exit c ON c.ID=a.ID;
```

but gives following error

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL serv er version for the right syntax to use near '(ifnull(EXIT_TIME,'NA')) as EXIT_TIME FROM tm_visitor a LEFT JOI N tm_belonging

Comment: caps lock will not help you get answer!!!!!!!!

Comment: You are hitting database from JSP using scriptlets. This is a really bad design. You should seriously think about db manipulation in your java code and just send the data you need to the page.

Comment: @pacman:i don't know other way of db manipulation please tell me how it can be manipulated in other way.

Answer (score 0):

you can avoid null values, use the ifnull function of MySQL,

The table with null value:

```
mysql> select * from test;
+------+---------+
| id   | name    |
+------+---------+
|    1 | Jcho360 |
|    1 | NULL    |
+------+---------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

the table with IFNULL function

```
mysql> select id, ifnull(name,'Its NOT NULL')as name from test;
+------+--------------+
| id   | name         |
+------+--------------+
|    1 | Jcho360      |
|    1 | Its NOT NULL |
+------+--------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

instead of 'its NOT NULL' you can put ' ' or anything else and you wont have null anymore

EDIT:

try

```
String sql="SELECT a.ID,a.VISITOR_TEXT,a.COMPANY_TEXT,a.CONTACT,a.PERSON_TO_MEET,
a.DEPARTMENT_TEXT,a.FLOOR,b.BELONGING_TYPE,b.BELONGING_TEXT ,a.INTIME,
 ifnull(c.EXIT_TIME,0) FROM tm_visitor a  
LEFT JOIN tm_belonging b ON b.BID=a.ID 
LEFT JOIN tm_exit c ON c.ID=a.ID limit "+i+",10";
```

Comment: @ybc126 I edit it, in the ifnull y put a 0, but you can put a "" or anything else to avoid that error